# Building mediapipe fails with both GCC and Clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, bazel, mediapipe

I am trying to build Hello World example of Mediapipe in C++. These are my exports in .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$(go env GOPATH)/bin
export GLOG_logtostderr=1
export CC=/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/bin/clang++
#export CC=/usr/bin/gcc
#export CXX=/usr/bin/g++
export BAZEL_CXXOPTS="-std=gnu++17"
```

then I run this, fallowing the instructions:

> bazelisk run --copt -DMESA_EGL_NO_X11_HEADERS --copt -DEGL_NO_X11 --sandbox_writable_path ~/.ccache --sandbox_debug --verbose_failures mediapipe/examples/desktop/hello_world:hello_world

the effect being "no member named 'max' in the global namespace" error on this line:

```
if (x->version == std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()) {
```

that's on Clang I've only used because GCC11 changed how it now doesn't include `<limits>` so with CC/CXX variables set to gcc/g++, it gives "'::max' has not been declared; did you mean std::max?" errors... did Clang made similar changes? I'm on Fedora, I don't have access to old GCC10.

Comment: What happens if you do - `if (x->version == std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()) {` ?

Comment: @moi it's not a part of the example, it's in the included mediapipe library :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mediapipe depends on an old version of [abseil c++](https://abseil.io/) that does not include [a commit](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/commit/5bf048b8425cc0a342e4647932de19e25ffd6ad7#diff-c2c26d26953e79ce20dd00dccad9e10e0249a17861480d58e73c4616786f2679) necessary to work on newer `libstdc++` versions. So, `com_google_absl` in the mediapipe [WORKSPACE](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/137e1cc7630524ea1c3a9b120985285fe43c8a3f/WORKSPACE#L23) needs an update.

Comment: do you think it's a matter of days they fix it, or they don't care that much?

Comment: I don't know if they're aware. Perhaps file a mediapipe issue?